# Agregar botones a las notificaciones push de fcm

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework, push-notification, fcm, capacitor

estoy intentando agregar dos botones a una notificacion push de fcm para que aparezca algo como esto, pero no logro hacer que funcione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intente agregarle un actions al data de los mensajes por json pero no funciono, alguna idea?.

```
actions: [{
        action: "delete",
        title: "Delete"
    }
```

estoy usando ionic 6 con capacitor y para las notificaciones el push notification de capacitor.